# Chrome extensions API for bookmarks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a Chrome extension that puts any new bookmark in a default folder.

The javascript seems correct but the bookmark is not moved to the specified location.
Do you know what's wrong with this code?

```
chrome.bookmarks.onCreated.addListener(function(id) {
  chrome.bookmarks.move(id, {parentId: '2'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the "bookmarks" permission in the extension manifest? You must declare the "bookmarks" permission in the extension manifest to use the bookmarks API.

```
      {
        "name": "My extension",
        ...
        "permissions": [
          "bookmarks"
        ],
        ...
      }
```

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks

Comment: I did, that's not the problem. I also must point out that adding a delay of 5 seconds sometimes makes it work. It seems as if the dialog that appears when you bookmark a page is interfering with the code.

Comment: Maybe it interferes indeed, in which case it looks like a bug in Chrome. Simply check and repeat if it's not moved in 100ms intervals using setTimeout.

Comment: @IJohnson, in Chrome there's only `chrome`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is fine, but the user experience is a little weird. When you create a bookmark, you'll see a prompt like the one below.

[Chrome bookmark modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdbBF.png)

When you click the "Done" button, the bookmark will be moved form its current location to the location specified in the dropdown.

I verified this behavior with the following snippet in an extension with the `bookmarks` permission.

```
// Copyright 2018 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

chrome.bookmarks.onCreated.addListener(function handleCreated(id, node) {
  console.log(`CREATED tab ${id} on ${node.parentId}`);

  console.log(`MOVEING (DEFAULT) tab ${node.id} to parent ${node.parentId}`);
  chrome.bookmarks.move(id, {parentId: '2'}, function afterMove(node) {
    console.log(`MOVED (DEFAULT) tab ${node.id} to parent ${node.parentId}`);
  });
});

chrome.bookmarks.onMoved.addListener(function handleMove(id, moveInfo) {
  console.log(`MOVE tab ${id} from ${moveInfo.oldParentId} to ${moveInfo.parentId}`);
});
```

When I created a bookmark, I saw the following log messages

```
CREATED tab 37 on 1
MOVEING (DEFAULT) tab 37 to parent 1
MOVE tab 37 from 1 to 2
MOVED (DEFAULT) tab 37 to parent 2
```

And when I clicked "Done" I saw

```
MOVE tab 37 from 2 to 1
```

With luck you can reproduce this behavior locally :)

Comment: Thank you for that. It seems the prompt moves the bookmark to the specified location **after** my code is executed, making it useless.

Comment: I don't know your exact use case but I don't think all hope is lost. The modal will remember the last location you saved to and automatically put new bookmarks there. Alternatively, you can hit `Esc` or click the X in the top right corner to cancel out of the move operation.

If you only want one bookmark you can also look for a creation event closely followed by a move, then redirect the bookmark to your desired location. Finally, you could make a copy of the bookmark and put it in the big bucket of bookmarks.